# Kerberos ticket in python without using subprocess

Tags: python, kerberos

Currently, I have the following code and it does the trick.

```
def negociateKRBticket():
    kinit = '/usr/bin/kinit'
    kinit_args = [kinit, '-kt', KEYTAB_PATH , USER_NAME]
    kinit = subprocess.Popen(kinit_args)
    kinit.wait()
```

Although I want to start using something more "pythonic" than a system call.
How can I drop the use of subprocess for this?